# Error SO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

Tags: programacion-asincrona

Hola buenas solo queria saber porque me aparece este errror llevo mucho tiempo intentando saber que es pero no puedo espero me puedan ayudar :(((

programa que dada una lista de N números enteros diferentes (0>N<=20), muestre:
El número mayor de la lista.
El número menor de la lista, ese es lo que tengo que hacer[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tienes numero declaradado como array de int (por eso el compilador se queja) si quiere puedes cambiar este valor el tamano del array (20) o puedes usar la siguiente sentencia para obtener el tamano del array.

**sizeof(numero)/sizeof(numero[0])**[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: O sea, cambiar en el ```for``` la variable ```número``` por otra variable digamos ```cant``` que se asigna antes del for con esa sentencia que dices ```sizeof(numero)/sizeof(numero[0])``` y ya estaría utilizando un ```int```